# How to rename files using R?

Tags: r, file, file-rename

I have a bunch of files that have *"_001"* in their file names. I followed a script posted online and I am at the directory where all my files are located:

```
filez <- list.files()
sapply(filez, function(X) {file.rename(from=x, to=sub(pattern="_001", replacement="", x))})
```

But I keep getting this error message:

> Error in file.rename(from = x, to = sub(pattern = "001", replacement = "")) :
> object 'x' not found".

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Your function calls for capital x, not lowercase x, that may help things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to do this with `sapply` at all. (This will bypass the problem you are having where the arguments to `file.rename` and `sub` should have been `X`.) Try this instead:

```
filez <- list.files()
file.rename(from=filez, to=sub(pattern="_001", replacement="", filez))
```